# sqlplus triggers compilation error and semicolon

Tags: oracle, triggers, sqlplus

It's for a school projet. I got 2 tables: `DOCTOR` and `PATIENTFILE`. If a `PATIENTFILE` is create or delete, I want to update the number of patients in the table `DOCTOR`. I do this trigger and I get the message:

> Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.

What's the error ?

Also I'd like to know something else: on which line in the trigger do I need to put semicolon at the end and what are the rules for that?

It's in Oracle SQL*Plus.

```
CREATE TRIGGER I_D_NbrPatients
AFTER INSERT OR DELETE ON PATIENTFILE
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF INSERTING THEN
UPDATE DOCTOR
SET nbrPatients = nbrPatients + 1;
WHERE (numDos = :NEW.numDos);
ELSEIF DELETING THEN
UPDATE DOCTOR
SET nbrPatients = nbrPatients - 1;
WHERE (numDos = :OLD.numDos);
END IF;
END;
/
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: "show errors" from sqlplus

Comment: The error is here: `ELSEIF` - use `ELSIF`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER I_D_NbrPatients
AFTER INSERT OR DELETE ON PATIENTFILE
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF INSERTING THEN
  UPDATE DOCTOR
  SET nbrPatients = nbrPatients + 1
  WHERE (numDos = :NEW.numDos);
ELSIF DELETING THEN
  UPDATE DOCTOR
  SET nbrPatients = nbrPatients - 1
  WHERE (numDos = :OLD.numDos);
END IF;
END;
/
```

You may go to this site for more details: [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_four.htm#i1039663)